# SVG as background image inlined in style attribute

Tags: html, css, svg, inline

I'm trying to inline an SVG as a background image of a `div`.
This works fine in a stylesheet:

```css
div {
  background-image:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width="30" height="25" viewBox="0 0 30 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><path d="M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3" stroke="%231CDFAF" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/></svg>');
}
```

As I'm using a templating language with PHP, I need to make the `stroke` of the SVG dynamic. To make it dynamic, I'm trying to inline the background image SVG in the HTML style attribute but am unable to escape the `"` characters in the SVG.

**What I've tried:**

Inlining with no escaping

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width="30" height="25" viewBox="0 0 30 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><path d="M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3" stroke="%231CDFAF" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/></svg>');"
>
</div>
```

Adding `\` before each `"`

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width=\"30\" height=\"25\" viewBox=\"0 0 30 25\" fill=\"none\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\"><path d=\"M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3\" stroke=\"%231CDFAF\" stroke-width=\"5\" stroke-linecap=\"round\"/></svg>');"
>
</div>
```

Replacing `"` with `%22`

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width=%2230%22 height=%2225%22 viewBox=%220 0 30 25%22 fill=%22none%22 xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 version=%221.1%22><path d=%22M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3%22 stroke=%22%231CDFAF%22 stroke-width=%225%22 stroke-linecap=%22round%22/></svg>');"
>
</div>
```

Is it possible to escape this inlined SVG?

Comment: If you are using php you may add a `<style>` in the head of the document and add something like `"background-image: url(\"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8...stroke='%23".$color."' stroke-width.....`

Comment: If you're only looking to change the stroke property, then this way of adding SVG's might be useful https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/ you can then use a normal inline CSS property to change the stroke. The only downside is you need a polyfill for IE

Comment: @Acidic Your `%22` solution works, as long as the div has a height. See edit to my answer.

Comment: I did think about the top two comments' solutions, but wasn't willing to give up on such a seemingly simple issue. Looking for an answer which solves my issue directly without any alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML escapes inside the attribute value: `&quot;` for a double quote, and (in this case not necessary, but if the need arises) `&apos;` for a single quote.

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width=&quot;30&quot; height=&quot;25&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 30 25&quot; fill=&quot;none&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; version=&quot;1.1&quot;><path d=&quot;M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3&quot; stroke=&quot;%231CDFAF&quot; stroke-width=&quot;5&quot; stroke-linecap=&quot;round&quot;/></svg>');"
>
<br style="line-height:25px">
</div>
```

(Note that I had to give the div some content in order to make the background visible; otherwise its height would have been 0. But that's just for the snippet here.)

Edit: as noted in the comments, the code also works when you use `%22` for quotes instead of `&quot;`.

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,<svg width=%2230%22 height=%2225%22 viewBox=%220 0 30 25%22 fill=%22none%22 xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 version=%221.1%22><path d=%22M3 14.0204L10.8806 21L27 3%22 stroke=%22%231CDFAF%22 stroke-width=%225%22 stroke-linecap=%22round%22/></svg>');"
>
<br style="line-height:25px">
</div>
```

So could something else have gone wrong in your code? Does your div have a height?

Comment: Escaping the double-quotes with `%22` works just as well.  I agree with you that OPs problem was probably just the div height issue.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Heh, I never thought to test that, since the OP already said it didn't work! So could you post an answer of your own, pointing out the OP's actual problem? Or do you want me to edit my answer?

Comment: Hmm I'm sure I had a height. In my real case, I was actually using a different more complicated SVG - I think I should've given my real SVG I was using.

We are using Twig for this project and at the end of the day my co-worker told me about using the `escape` filter in Twig with `html_attr` https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html

This worked with my more complicated SVG by literally escaping almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complicated SVG, you will need to escape more than just quotes.

The project I was working with is written with the Twig templating language which comes with an [`escape`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html) filter which can be used with `html_attr`.

For example:

```
<div
  style="background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,{{ '<svg>...</svg>' | escape('html_attr') }}');"
>
</div>
```

The code for `escape('html_attr')` can be found here: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/8a78e8bd20f228469cba345284ef8496f84010dd/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php#L1117

It essentially escapes any character that does not match this regex: `[^a-zA-Z0-9,\.\-_]`

The main characters necessary to escape are:

```
"    &quot;
&    &amp;
<    &lt;
>    &gt;
```

The following JavaScript can be used as a utility to escape an SVG string for use as a HTML attribute:

```
function escapeHtmlAttr(str) {
  return str.replace(/["&<>]/g, char => {
    switch (char) {
      case '"':
        return '&quot';

      case '&':
        return '&amp';

      case '<':
        return '&lt';

      case '>':
        return '&gt';
    }
    return char;
  });
}

// Usage
const str = `<svg>...</svg>`;           // Your SVG
const escapedStr = escapeHtmlAttr(str); // Escaped SVG
```